# How to pass parameters for POST web-service for group API for linkedin in IOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api

I have tried to call below web-service

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships
```

as mentioned on [Linkedin Developer: Group API](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#)

Only problem i'm facing is how to pass parameters as json format instead of XML

All suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's API was originally build in the XML days before JSON was popular.  As a result, the default expected data format for sending data in is in XML.  If you want to send your data to LinkedIn in JSON format, you need to add the following HTTP headers to your request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-li-format: json
```

Additional information about using the LinkedIn REST APIs can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api